# Adding attributes to relationship class at later date using ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arccatalog, relationship-class

I have a relationship class that could use a new attribute (or two or three).  I have looked for a way to do this in ArcCatalog and have not discovered it yet.  I have:

1. Opened the Relationship Class Properties by right clicking on the Relationship class.
2. Previewed the Relationship Class and right-clicked in the Column Headings.
3. Looked in ArcToolbox>Data Management Tools>Relationship Classes.

None of these attempts have resulted in a new attribute.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an attribute to a relationship class you need to use ArcMap.

1. In ArcMap, use the Add Data button to add your relationship to the .mxd.  It will come in as a table.
2. From the Table of Contents, open the table by doing a Right Click>Open.
3. In the table view, click Table Options>Add Field.
4. Set the properties of your new field and click OK.

Your new attribute is now in the Relationship Class.

Alternatively, to add the attribute from ArcToolbox, you can use Data Management>Fields>Add Field.